# MySQL delete left join found in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete rows that are found in another table like below

```
DELETE l, lk, lp, sl
FROM listings l
LEFT JOIN listings_keywords lk
ON lk.listing_sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN listings_properties lp
ON lp.object_sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN source_listings sl
ON sl.listing_id = l.sid
WHERE l.user_sid = 4645
AND l.sid IN (SELECT listing_id FROM source_listings)
```

It seems to create an error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1093 You can't specify target table 'sl' for update in FROM clause
```

I'm trying to delete whatever is found under `source_listings` with specific user_sid = 4645

Is there a way to do this to fix this issue so that any rows that are found with those conditions are deleted from those four tables specified in the SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this

```
AND l.sid IN (SELECT listing_id FROM source_listings)
```

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
Since you are removing rows from table `source_listings` , you can't use it in select statement .

Apart from error , the subquery is not required since you are already doing a JOIN between 
`listings` table and `source_listings` table

Comment: Would I need to do `inner join` for `sl` table if I want to include just the ones that are related to the ones found on this table?

Comment: Yes ... inner join returns only the matching rows from both table

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the table to be updated on a subquery - `source_listings`. If you can't get rid of that statement, you need to force the referenced table to exist as a temporary table generated by MySQL:

```
DELETE l, lk, lp, sl
FROM listings l
LEFT JOIN listings_keywords lk
ON lk.listing_sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN listings_properties lp
ON lp.object_sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN source_listings sl
ON sl.listing_id = l.sid
WHERE l.user_sid = 4645
AND l.sid IN
SELECT listing_id FROM (SELECT listing_id FROM source_listings) X
```